# Where can I configure groups like "stock.group_stock_user" with Open ERP?

Tags: security, openerp-7

There are several groups for view interface of Open ERP. (`groups="base.group_user"`, `"stock.group_stock_user"` etc).

It seems I can create own custom one. But, where can I create and modify manage them? How can I configure which ERP users belong to this group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups is the key role in **Odoo (formally OpenERP) Security** based on the user security group is the major role for implement any module for specifically user access.

**How to create the Group and update with the existing group in OpenERP :**

I am just updating the existing security Group from Fleet Module in OpenERP

```
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="0">
       <record id="fleet.group_fleet_user" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Staff User</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="fleet.module_fleet_category"/>
       </record>
       <record id="group_fleet_line_manager" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Line Manager</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="fleet.module_fleet_category"/>
             <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('fleet.group_fleet_user'))]"/>
        </record>
        <record id="fleet.group_fleet_manager" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Manager</field>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_fleet_line_manager'))]"/>
            <field name="category_id" ref="fleet.module_fleet_category"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**id** and **model** are the key  attribute while creating the user level security based on Group  of **record** tag in OpenERP

**id** is the uniquely  identify each group record

**model** which is used to create the group based on group name into the database table

**Group 1:**

**id="fleet.group_fleet_user"**

which is update the existing group name  from the fleet module

**Group 2:**

**id="group_fleet_line_manager"**

Which is used to create new group for fleet and add that group between two groups from the group selection from the user security in user form view.

**Group 3:**

**id="fleet.group_fleet_manager"**

which is update the existing group name from the fleet module.

**you can add the users from the Security Group in following Way :**

[image]

I hope this should helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks. @DasaDiYa Can I manually create my own **fleet_security.xml** in my custom inherited "Fleet" module to add new groups and override original group settings?

Also what does **ir.model.access.csv** do? It looks redundant of what I can do via interface. I can find it in both original **Fleet module** and my **Custom inherited** module.

Comment: Yes can do it as well and when u add the new record in ir.model.access.csv file then its create a new record in  the Access Control List   you may try to nevigate through this way Settings >>Security  >>Access Control List ,it is not the redundant but its a override the old one.